# Canvas App OAuth Fails in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, oauth2, authentication, canvas

I have a canvas app I am making Salesforce1 compatable. Things work fine when I log in to the desktop and use it is "Salesforce1 mode", but when I try and access it in my Salesforce1 with my dev org, it does not go beyond the loading screen. I have a suspision that it is wanting me to authorize it's access to my account, but it is not prompting me to allow it. Additionally, I have set the app pre-authorize by admin, and according to this flow chart as I understand it,
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/Content/user_flow_oauth.htm
I should not be prompted to allow it. Any insight is greatly appreciated.